# How prove this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x+n)^2\sin^2(x+n) =\infty$?

Tags: limits, solution-verification

> Let $$f\left(x\right)=x^2\sin^2\left(x\right)\,,\qquad (~0\ <\ x\ <\ 1~)$$

show that

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x+n)=+\infty$$

**My try: **

let

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x+n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(x+n)^2\sin^2(x+n)$$
>   since
>   $$\sin^2(x+n)\le 1$$
>   then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(x+n)^2\sin^2(x+n)\longrightarrow +\infty$$

**my try is true? if not true,then How can prove it,Thank you**

Comment: you have to prove that $\sin^2{(x+n)}>0$. Hint: $\sin(x+n)= \sin(x)\cos(n)+\cos(x)\sin(n)$ with $n \in N$ and $0<x<1<\pi/2$

Comment: and also bigger than $k(n)/n^2$ for a $k(n)$ that gets larger without limit as $n\to\infty$

Comment: It isn't $\infty$, the limit doesn't exist as it just oscillates between $0$ and $(x+n)^2$.

Comment: How quickly does $(x+n)/\pi$ approach an integer?

Comment: I feel like this may not be true, because sin(x+n) will take values arbitrarily close to zero infinitely often (as the points $x + n$ mod $2\pi$ are dense in $[0,2\pi]$ no matter how large you restrict $n$ to be). Mixing sin and cos with discrete limits is never a nice thing to work with. Taking the subsequence of numbers that are integer parts of something like $2\pi n -x$ may be a good route to go down for disproving it - possibly having to use half angle forumulae to get the sin term to decay quite quick enough.

Comment: @Matt: You are right about density. But it may still happen that to get small enough sines, you have to go so far in the sequence that the factor $(x+n)^2$ will compensate. For example it should be easy to prove that $\sin^2(x+n)<1/N$ for some $n$ less than constant times $N$, but?? Anyway, this question is a problem of Diophantine approximation rather than just limits. Basic techniques from advanced calculus courses cannot take one anywhere.

Comment: Hmm. On second thought I now agree with Matt that the limit may not exist.

Comment: The subsequence $n_k=[ (((2\pi k)^4 - x^4)^1/4 ]$ (or very similar) should disprove it; $sin^2(x+n_k)$ will be bounded by $|n_k+x-2\pi k|^2$, which will be bounded by some multiple of $\frac{1}{k^6}$ (using $a^4-b^4=(a-b)(a^3 + a^2b + ab^2 + b^3)$), whereas $(x+n_k)^2$ will only behave like $k^2$. I don't have time to check the details at the moment though.

Comment: There is something missing in the question: what is the definition of $f(x)$ outside of $(0,1)$? Are you taking the limit of functions, or the limit of function values?